# Как передать данные к более "древнему" родительскому компоненту?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, передача-данных

Мне нужно, чтобы данные от дочернего компонента Li доходили до родительского компонента 3-4 уровня -- Li -> Menu -> App

Вот мой код, пытался использовать **onChange**, но он работает только для форм

```js
export default function App(){
    const style = {
        maxWidth: 1200 + 'px',
        margin: '0 auto',
        padding: '0 15px'
    }

    const handleClick = (value: any) => {
        console.log(value);
    }

    return(
        <div style = {style} >
            <Menu test2 = {handleClick} />
        </div>
    ) 
}

function Menu(props: any){
    const [click , setClick] = useState('')

    const style = {
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    }


    const handleTest = () => {
        props.test2(click);
    }

    const handleClick = (value: any) => {
        setClick(value);
    }
    return (
        <nav data-test = {handleTest}>
            <ul style = {style}>
                <Li test = {handleClick}>hi</Li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

function Li(props: any){
    const style = {
        listStyle: 'none',
        fontSize: 24 + 'px'
    }

    const [click, setClick] = useState('');
    const handleClick = () => {
        props.test('pidoras')
        setClick('hi');
    } 
    return (
        <li 
            style = {style}
            onClick = {handleClick}>
            {props.children} <br />
            {click}
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: Вы когда передаете функцию handleClick, в дочерних компонентах должны ее так же пробрасывать как props.* А у вас она теряется уже на втором компоненте.

Comment: а каким событием мне это делать? Если это делать также onClick, то это как то костыльно и + браузер будет отрабатывать 2 клика

Comment: В данном случае лучше посмотреть в сторону [`Context`](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже пример, как можно пробрасывать функции из родительского компонента в дочерний любой вложенности.

По сути, надо просто передавать саму фукнцию в пропсы дочернего компонента.

Создадим родительский компонент, в котором будет состояние и рендер дочернего компонента. В дочерний компонент `Second` мы передаем фукнцию **setVal** в параметре **click** `click={setVal}`. Так же передадим значения для рендера(массив) **renderData**.

```
const App = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [renderData, setRenderData] = useState([
    { name: "one", value: 1 },
    { name: "two", value: 2 },
    { name: "three", value: 3 }
  ]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Second click={setVal} renderData={renderData} />
      <hr />
      {val}
    </div>
  );
};
```

В компоненте `Second` мы принимам параметры **click** и **renderData**. В компоненте первый рендер массива передаем "как есть" переменную click(в ней лежит функция из App) и сам элемент в компонент **Line**. Во второй рендр(для примера) передадим фукнцию **modify**, которая будет добавлять 10 к полученному значению.

```
const Second = ({ clickб renderData }) => {
  const modify = (val) => {
    click(val + 10);
  };
  return (
    <>
      Пробрасываем функцию как есть:
      <br />
      {lines.map((item) => (
        <Line key={item.name} data={item} click={click} />
      ))}
      <br />
      Пробрасываем модифицированную функцию:
      <br />
      {lines.map((item) => (
        <Line key={item.name} data={item} click={modify} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Сам компонент `Line` принимает на вход **data**(Данные для отрисовки) и **click**(функция, которая будет установлена для события **onClick()**

```
const Line = ({ data, click }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => click(data.value)}>{data.name}</button>;
};
```

Таким образом, мы протянули функцию через 2 компонента. При необходимости, ее можно и через 10 протянуть.

Работающий пример данного ответа в песочнице [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-nobel-8wc5qt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: выглядит что лучше бы про Context рассказал, чем пробросы туда сюда с вероятность что-то забыть

Comment: @Grundy да, при больших расстояних контекст лучше, однако был вопрос, как протащить функцию по нескольким компонентам - вот, показал. Возможно, это не будет использоваться, однако знать и понимать, как это делается, надо.

Comment: @Grundy, так Context передаёт свойства от родителя к любому потомку, но не обратно, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @AlexPapa Это можно воспринимать как глобальное хранилище данных, доступное любому компоненту вне зависимости от иерархии.

Comment: @AlexPapa. ошибаешься - Context это просто глобальная переменная, к которой есть доступ у любого компонента внутри его

Comment: @SwaD, ну тут не совсем вне зависимости от иерархии, главное чтобы внутри провайдера были - если снаружи то доступа уже не будет, с этой стороны иерархия важна