# React. Как передать данные state в родительский компонент?

Tags: reactjs, usestate

Делаю свой первый проектик на React.Есть кнопка бургера. при клике на которую должна открываться навигация , при этом бургер анимируется. С анимацией всё понятно , сделал через useState, теперь не понимаю как состояние передать в state  родителя чтоб далее открывать навигацию.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import '../headerBurger/headerBurger.css';

const HeaderBurger = function(){
    const [isActive , setActive] = useState(false);
    const handleToggle =()=>{
        setActive(!isActive)
    }
    
    return(
        <div className='header_burger-content'>
            <button onClick={handleToggle}  className={`burger header_burger ${isActive ? "burger_active" : ""} `}><span className="burger__line"></span></button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default HeaderBurger;
```

Comment: Передать из родителя ф-цию, которая будет выполняться, когда обновляется state

Comment: [Пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1547345/) [Пример 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496465/)